# How can I get a random uint or the last digit of float in HLSL/GLSL?

Tags: opengl, glsl, hlsl

I just need a random uint, better ranging from 0-6, but there is no enumeration type in openGL. I learned that I can get a random float ranging 0-1 from the code below:

```
frac(sin(dot(uv, float2(12.9898, 78.233))) * 43758.5453123)
```

I tried to do 1/above and get floor(), but it doesn't work. Then how can I get a random int? or is there a way to get the last digit of the float(so presumably still random)?

Comment: @KaiBurjack Thanks, I have read that post. It is where I get the random float, but doesn't give the idea of uint.

Comment: @KaiBurjackk Yeah, that's what I just come up with and does the job. However, modulo method like % and fmod() seem to remove the randomness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's define what we mean by "random". In the context of this answer, a "random" variable is a variable whose values are *unpredictable*. That is, there is no *function* that determines/computes an outcome for the random variable when being evaluated (with any possible inputs). Or at least, no such function has been found (yet).

Obviously, when we are talking about *computing* here, there is no such thing as a *true* random variable as described above, because *anything* we do in computing (and by extension in a shader) is necessarily bound to the set of functions that are *computable*.

Your proposed function in the question:

```c
f(uv) = frac(sin(dot(uv, float2(12.9898, 78.233))) * 43758.5453123)
```

*is* just a computable function. It takes as input a vector `uv`, which itself is a deterministic/computable value - such as derived from a built-in or custom varying variable giving you the "coordinates" of the current fragment.

After evaluation, the function's result itself was computable/deterministic and happens to be a value (which the input vector `uv` maps to). Taking different IEEE 754 rules and precisions aside (which may vary between different GPUs such as desktop ones and mobile ones), the function itself is purely deterministic/computable and therefore does not give you a *random* value.

We humans may think that the output is random, because we lack the intuition for the functions used to compute the result, such that when we "see" a number  `0.623513632` followed by another number `0.9734126` for only slight variations in the input vector, we could draw the conclusion that "yeah, that looks pretty random", when it fact it obviously isn't. It is just what that function computed, given two input values.

So, when you already have a deterministic function like the above and wanted to obtain values in the closed range [0, 6] from it as a GLSL `uint`, you can simply scale the output of said function by multiplying the function's result with `7.0` and truncating the result:

```c
g(uv) = uint(f(uv) * 7.0)
```

If you wanted to obtain *true* random numbers drawn from a random variable (whose deterministic function simply hasn't been found yet), you can obtain such values from universe background radiation (such as from random.org) and use that as an input to your shader (such as via textures or buffer objects).

But, from a computational perspective, a shader is just a function taking in values (ints, floats, ...) and computing (by means of computable functions) a deterministic result.
All we can do is to shuffle/scramble/diffuse the input bits in such a way, that the result "looks" like random to us. We then call these "pseudo-random" values.

Taking this a step further, we could now ask the question of the distribution quality of the obtained pseudo-random values. This has two qualities:

1. how evenly distributed are the pseudo-random values in their domain/interval? I.e. do all possible values have the same probability of occurring? Or: Do you even *want* to have uniformly-distributed values or should the values follow another distribution (like Guassian?)
2. how well are two values drawn from two sequential input values *spaced* apart? I.e. what is the *frequency* of the pseudo-random values?

There are different (deterministic) algorithms/functions depending on which distribution and which frequency spectrum your values should have. But first, you should define an answer to the two questions for your use-case.
And by the way, the commonly used function in your question to obtain pseudo-random numbers in a shader has a *terrible* distribution quality.

Last but not least, it should also be mentioned that *true* randomness (i.e. non-determinism), like when you *do* use an entropy source as input values, is oftentimes an undesirable property in computation, because it:

1. makes it difficult to repeat the same computation / output when needed, which is useful in various algorithms in the context of path tracing
2. makes it difficult to reproduce/debug/inspect your function for a particular run when every following execution/run will yield a different output

Comment: Hi, Kai. Thanks for the explanation. I do know that there is only pseudo-random in computer. It is just modulo method does not even produce such pseudo-random like unit(frac(...)*7). Instead, it rolls back to constant, so I wonder if there are extra mechanisms controlling for randomness.